# How can I add a menu link to a page with a form in DrupalGap?

Tags: forms, javascript

I made a custom page that has a form on it. How can I add a menu link to the authorised user menu? There is this very useful documentation http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Menus/Adding_Links_to_Menus but **how do I get the path to the custom page with the form?**

In settings.js I have added this and the new link shows up.

```
drupalgap.settings.menus['user_menu_authenticated'] = {
  options: menu_popup_get_default_options(),
  links: [
{
  title: 'My Account',
  path: 'user',
  options: {
    attributes: {
      'data-icon': 'user',
      'class': 'ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right'
    }
  }
},
{
  title: 'Logout',
  path: 'user/logout',
  options: {
    attributes: {
      'data-icon': 'delete'
    }
  }
}, //NEW LINK
 {
  title: 'Buy points',
 // path: 'user/logout', // what path?
 page_callback: 'drupalgap_get_form',
  page_arguments: ['my_module_payment_form'],
  options: {
    attributes: {
      'data-icon': 'delete'
    }
  }
}
  ]
};
```

In my_module.js I have added the form like so and it shows up:

```
function my_module_menu() {
  try {
  var items = {};
  items['in-app'] = {
    title: 'get points',
    page_callback: 'drupalgap_get_form',
    page_arguments: ['my_module_payment_form']
};
return items;
}
   catch (error) {
      console.log('my_module_menu - ' + error);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out finally:

```
path: 'in-app'
```

Comes from the hook_menu items array.